# Binding to dynamically created WPF UI objects in an MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I have a UI which I'm trying to migrate to use best practises, in this case MVVM. I've come across something which I'm not sure how to handle in the best way.

The UI is a list of orders with some filter options above - Order Source and Date. Source being where the order came from, ie. Telephone, Ebay, Amazon, etc, which are all defined in the database.

The filter UI for selecting sources is a group of ribbon toggle buttons, one for each source - so the user can select any combination of sources and the list of orders will display only orders from selected sources. This is built up from the database like so:

```
<Custom:RibbonGroup Header="Sources" ItemsSource="{Binding Sources}">
    <Custom:RibbonGroup.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Data:OrderSource}">
            <Custom:RibbonToggleButton Label="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Custom:RibbonGroup.ItemTemplate>
</Custom:RibbonGroup>
```

("Sources" being an ObservableCollection of OrderSource objects, loaded from the DB.)

My 'Model' for the Filter Control is an object with the various filter options as properties, ie:

```
public class OrdersFilter
{
    public List<int> SourceIds { get; set; }
    public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }
}
```

The filter is then passed in to the Orders Repository GetOrders method:

```
public IEnumerable<Order> GetOrders(OrdersFilter filter)
{
    return this.context.Orders.Where(order => filter.SourceIds.Contains(order.SourceId) && order.Date >= filter.FromDate && order.Date < filter.ToDate);
}
```

the results of which are bound to an ObservableCollection on the ViewModel for the orders list.

Now this is where it gets tricky. The ViewModel and bindings for the dates are dead easy - just a couple of DateTime properties that are bound to the SelectedDateTime property of the DatePickers.

I don't even know where to start binding a bunch of dynamically generated toggle buttons in the UI to a list of IDs in the model though!

Am I going about this in completely the wrong way? Or is there an easy solution to this?

Comment: Do you want to choose ids in UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to create a new ViewModel object for OrderSource, such as OrderSourceViewModel, that would contain "IsUserInterested" boolean property.

After that you bind it on ToggleButton.

```
<Custom:RibbonToggleButton Label="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsUserInterested}" />
```

Now you either need to create a new button, "Apply" that will fetch necessary orders from the database, as so:

```
orders = GetOrders(new OrdersFilter{ 
                                      SourceIds = OrderSources
                                      .Where(x => x.IsUserInterested)
                                      .Select(x => x.Id)});
```